# Erro ao compilar o software HM (Padrão HEVC) na máquina virtual linux

Tags: linux

Segui os seguintes passos:

1 - Criei uma máquina virtual Linux no meu Mac

2- Baixei o software HM do site (https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_HEVCSoftware/tags/HM-16.0/)

3 - Entrei na pasta HM-16.0/build/linux

4 - Rodei "make all" para compilar o HM e apareceu os seguintes erros mostrados na imagem ao falhar a compilação.

Não encontrei nada na internet que pudesse me ajudar. Alguém aqui poderia me dar uma força se possível? Como faço para consertar essas falhas?

Obs.: O HM é o software padrão do HEVC (novo padrão de codificação de vídeo criado em 2013).

[image]

Comment: Qual a versão do GCC?

Comment: Minha versão do gcc é 6.2.0

Comment: Tem que ser essa versão? Ou pode tentar a versão mais nova? Creio que a versão 16.3 não deva dar esse erro.

Comment: O -Werror, faz com que os warnings se tornem erros, no caso esse é o de misleading-indentation(https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GCC6-Misleading-Indentation).

Comment: na versão 16.3 o código teve a indentação corrigida

Comment: Usa as instruções do fórum deles deles https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/trac/hevc/ticket/1445